# ORACLE CASE and DATES

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem in this query

```
SELECT ID, MYDATE
  FROM MY_DATABASE
 WHERE (CASE
           WHEN TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'D') IN ('3',
                                           '4',
                                           '5',
                                           '6',
                                           '7')
           THEN
                  MYDATE > (SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL ('1', 'DAY'))
              AND TO_CHAR (MYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') !=
                     TO_CHAR (MYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D') IN ('2') THEN MYDATE > (SYSDATE -NUMTODSINTERVAL('2','DAY')) AND TO_CHAR(MYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') != TO_CHAR (MYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    ELSE NULL
    END)=1
```

Oracle said that one specific word is missing
Between "MYDATE(HERE)>(SYSDATE "

I also try to make a subquery after the 'THEN'

I what to see the IDs.
If today is "Monday". the number  of Monday is '2'.

show me the id in last two days without counting today's id's

And if Tuesday to Saturday the numbers are 3 to 7 show me the id in last 1 day without counting today's id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid syntax. Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
select id, mydate
from my_database
where mydate > sysdate - case when to_char(sysdate, 'D') in (3, 4, 5, 6, 7) then 1
                              when to_char(sysdate, 'D') in (2)             then 2
                         end;
```

---

I don't know what you meant by condition

```
  AND TO_CHAR(MYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') != TO_CHAR (MYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

as it is never true; you're comparing same values, they are never *different*.

**[EDIT]** You commented that you want to *skip* today's rows.

In that case, a simple option is to use

```
and trunc(mydate) <> trunc(sysdate)
```

Note, though, that index (if you have it) on `mydate` column wouldn't be used, unless you created a function-based index. In that case, use a little bit more complex option.

For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.
```

Right now is

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
----------------
12.09.2023 21:54
```

Condition that skips today's `mydate`:

```
SQL> with test (mydate) as
  2    (select to_date('02.09.2023 14:23', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  3     select to_date('12-09.2023 08:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4     select to_date('20.09.2023 18:55', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  5    )
  6  select mydate
  7  from test
  8  where mydate < trunc(sysdate)
  9     or mydate >= trunc(sysdate + 1);

MYDATE
----------------
02.09.2023 14:23
20.09.2023 18:55

SQL>
```

Comment: AND TO_CHAR(MYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') != TO_CHAR (MYDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) this is for not include the id of today

Comment: It’s not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please update your question with sample data and the result you are trying to achieve - with, if necessary, the rules that need to be applied to achieve the result

Comment: Have a look at edited answer, please; I added some more info.

Comment: I check the fist query that You sent and actually works really good. I will add the part of skip todays rows. Thank you so much!! One question that query works based on the actual day right?  For example Tomorrow is Wednesday so the info will show only the rows on Wednesday

Comment: You're welcome. As of question you've just asked: I don't quite understand what you are saying. Additional condition (posted in EDIT) won't let rows whose MYDATE is equal to SYSDATE to be displayed. It'll work on any day, Wednesday included.

Comment: The final line will cause nothing to be displayed. Did you mean `and mydate >= trunc(sysdate - 1)`?

Comment: Hm, no; actually, I meant OR, not AND. I added example which illustrates what I was trying to say. Thank you for noticing!

Comment: Sorry my English is not good enough but I do my best... but at least I can find the results I was looking for, thanks 

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad if you made it work.

Answer (score 1):

> If today is "Monday" [...] show me the id in last two days without counting today's id's.
>
> And if Tuesday to Saturday [...] show me the id in last 1 day without counting today's id's

`TO_CHAR(date_value, 'D')` gives different values in different territories around the world (i.e. In America, Sunday is the 1st day of the week; in Europe, Monday is the 1st day of the week; in the Middle-East, Saturday is the 1st day of the week; and in Bangladesh, Friday is the 1st day of the week). This makes it difficult to use `TO_CHAR(date_value, 'D')` internationally. Instead, you can compare the day to the start of the ISO week (which is always midnight Monday) using `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')`.

Your code would be:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       MYDATE
FROM   MY_DATABASE
WHERE  MYDATE <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) -- without today
AND    MYDATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - CASE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
                                  WHEN 0                -- Monday
                                  THEN INTERVAL '2' DAY
                                  WHEN 6                -- Sunday
                                  THEN INTERVAL '0' DAY
                                  ELSE INTERVAL '1' DAY -- Tuesday to Saturday
                                  END;
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer plus the answer of the other guy helps me to get what I was looking for! you all are awesome 